# Build Hierarchy Parent-Child Relationship in dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I have a requirement for building hierarchy parent-child relationship and load it into salesforce,input is in below xml format.

'**Parent**' and '**Child**' are two lookup fields in salesforce and output should look like

`<ZHZUOR>04</ZHZUOR>` is a parent of `<ZHZUOR>03</ZHZUOR`>, 
`<ZHZUOR>03</ZHZUOR>` is a parent of `<ZHZUOR>02</ZHZUOR>` and so on....(based on ZKUNNR)

Any help?

Input Sample :

```
<Z1KNVH SEGMENT="1">    
 <VKORG>AR01</VKORG>    
 <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>    
 <SPART>09</SPART>    
 <HITYP>A</HITYP>    
   <Z1KNVH_2 SEGMENT="1">
      <ZHZUOR>04</ZHZUOR>
      <ZKUNNR>0011503063</ZKUNNR>
      <NAME>OTHERS AR</NAME>
 </Z1KNVH_2>


 <Z1KNVH_2 SEGMENT="1">

     <ZHZUOR>03</ZHZUOR>
     <ZKUNNR>0011503061</ZKUNNR>
     <NAME>OTHERS SOCO</NAME>
 </Z1KNVH_2>


   <Z1KNVH_2 SEGMENT="1">

         <ZHZUOR>02</ZHZUOR>
         <ZKUNNR>0010907232</ZKUNNR>
         <NAME>OTHERS LA</NAME>
   </Z1KNVH_2>    

     <Z1KNVH_2 SEGMENT="1">
            <ZHZUOR>01</ZHZUOR>
            <ZKUNNR>0030036919</ZKUNNR>
            <NAME>ALL OTHERS AMERICAS</NAME>
     </Z1KNVH_2>

 </Z1KNVH>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What Dataweave transformation have your tried? Do you get any errors? What errors are they? We need a bit more info to help you.

Comment: Thanks Chad for your response,but i got solution now.